# Sending a variable from JavaScript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I've created a game that collects a User's time on the browser with JavaScript. What I'd like to do is grab that JavaScript data and send it to the backend, which is written in Java (I'm using a local server running on Tomcat). How can I accomplish this?

I've looked into AJAX and here is what I've come up with...

```
          var myTime = // however long it took for user to win game

          var data = {}
          data["myTime"] = myTime;

          $.ajax({
              type : "POST",
              url : "/path-to/hosting/save",
              data : JSON.stringify(data),
              dataType : 'json',
              timeout : 100000,
              contentType:'application/json',
              success : function(data) {
                  console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
              },
              error : function(e) {
                  console.log("ERROR: ", e);
              },
              done : function(e) {
                  console.log("DONE");
              }
          });
```

When I finish the game, I receive this error on the console:
statusText:"parsererror"

My initial thought was that I didn't form my JSON correctly, but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the data type you use in Java to get the data send from the Javascript

Comment: I've been using this as a reference: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-refactoring-a-jquery-ajax-post-example/

I created the same path to receive the data. I also created the HostingForm class to contain my variable myTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code it seems like myTime is a single value why you store it in array you can pass that as follows

var myTime = // however long it took for user to win game

```
      //var data = {}
      //data["myTime"] = myTime;

      $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : "/path-to/hosting/save",
          data : JSON.stringify({
            'myTime': myTime                
          }),
          dataType : 'json',
          timeout : 100000,
          contentType:'application/json',
          success : function(data) {
              console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
          },
          error : function(e) {
              console.log("ERROR: ", e);
          },
          done : function(e) {
              console.log("DONE");
          }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks Nisal. The data type that JavaScript gives me is a "Number".
I've tried changing my data type on the backend as a "float" and "double", but there is still a parsing error. 

Here is the response: 
      {"timestamp":1509248487870,"status":400,"error":"Bad 
Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException","message":"Required double parameter 'myTime' is not present","path":"/path-to/hosting/save"}

Comment: I see. We forgot to add a key for the value. However, I am now receiving this error in my console:

ERROR
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Per our setup above, this means that the ajax call was not a success. Do you have any other idea or tip about what the issue may be?

Comment: Actually, it does work now. I wrote some System.print.out lines and I am able to grab the data. Thank you!

Comment: Anytime hope you will be able to fix the server side problem as well.